# Subclass override return type of the base class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to override a method that is defined in the `super` class, however I am getting an error that says:

> Property 'get' in type 'Model' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'DB'.

What can I do to override this? It works with the generated JavaScript, and I would like to not have to make `DB.get()` return `Promise<any>` which also works.

```
type NonAbstractModel<T extends Model> = (new () => T) & typeof Model
type RowDataPacket = {}

export class Collection<T> {
  protected _items: T[] = []
  public add(item:T){ this._items.push(item) }
}

export class DB {
  public async get(): Promise<RowDataPacket[]> { 
    // Query a database, this is just dummy data
    return [{}, {}, {}]
  }
}

export abstract class Model extends DB {

  public static convert<T extends Model>(model: NonAbstractModel<T>, data: RowDataPacket[]): Collection<T> {
    let c = new Collection<T>()
    for(let i of data) {
      let m = new model()
      c.add(m)
    }
    return c
  }

  public async get<T extends Model>():Promise<Collection<T>>{
    return Model.convert(<NonAbstractModel<T>>this.constructor, await super.get())
  }
}
```

### How the two work:

#### DB

When the DB class is used, we have no idea the type of Model because a model is based on a database table, but we do know that the results will be an array of database items.

#### Model

When a Model is used we do know what the type of Model is, so we have the ability to convert the packet data into a collection of models (One Model class for each row item).

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gOwIICMDOwBOBDAxsAWTgBMIAbAHgBUoIAPYCBYtKI0sgPigF4oAKBBADuAgJS9uVCQDIooSHABmbEuQBQC6ACU4wgCLZg2AAp4A1hGC8oAbwC+69fTBxM13GWxpWAYThkZBD4AJaI1Ny26lBQYJhwjPgQxFAA+iGMALZoAFxQVADaALo2xdGxAK4oZCG4UNjExPwZEJk50rbyABYhaAB06Vn9YBVoXc1ZEo6OznSu7lCe3qz6AEJ25SPVtfVoIAh1AOZW-GJ5JvGZvRAUugZGphZWxZFQ5TEA9B9QAIoVEJgQPUoMQHihvBAADTdXpQWEAK1G1mIFUymSBoOM7ygmCsFUwCCgBQc0JJdnsRXK0ycLjc1mw6CweA8Xh8qg4tAYTBYUDWG02VRqdQwRh2uEQADcAcBqJzGMxWOxyJx+Jk1GQ8vBkIycPglZQqJxoZjsHk7oZjGZcJZgMUzlB-IFgsAwggIhsYjEgh4bEJRI6gqFwobTtilG5+N64VBlCCHhIop7PVHMr6RFA1RxQ0mYrg+g0mpkxNjHEnccB8YTcFSnDEtkLdvsjlZZfR5Tz9Sqzhc4Fc0DcA87XRFOInPeXK+zyH1xQgpe5+BQtagMLrCOqR8Aev1Z6uKvg3NDsMJsBkoGgKpBMH1jsBTsWYtMgA)

Comment: What do you think should happen if I do `async function hmm(db: DB): Promise<number> { return (await db.get()).length }` followed by `hmm(new Model()).then(n => console.log(n));`?  At runtime I'd expect an error (unless `Collection` happens to have a `length` property, and if it does, replace `.length` with anything `Array` has that `Collection` doesn't), but `class Model extends DB` requires that it should work.  Not sure how to advise you since your `Model` clearly is not a `DB`.

Comment: The function signatures do not match, did you intend for `get` to be `abstract`?

Comment: Not sure if this is of use but might help out: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBKEDuAFAhgYwGtgYARXGXOAXjgG8BfAKCdEljnwBtcBnXuAGEIXLsHwwAlhAB2AHgAqAPnrNW4aPFwAjXjCgF43PgNIAhRSrpM4cMAFdtXSfjh9EM1wHMSACgCUAFxw2FAQALaSvMByvgoA2gC6-gA+GDgExGQUuFZwNracsrwiwAB0XBBevgDk5sE+MDX+BbZQJPZQMnDxjIkFzGpsmpw8-HAAshAAJsBclnCgMMAy06YWyvQFDk4ubrwe3n5BoRFRMcKi4lKylkrWhUUyJWIVVbVTs1wNJM2tcO0YJ1ujJgJghCIxBJpDIAgMmEMNBxjOMAGIQCALJYrNZwcwLaxqfDFeDhGZzGhwUHgz5zAIAbiYZK+ZUacKYxOe8AAZhjKdS4OiIAymLyIKzjiwgA

Comment: @Leon No it shouldn't be abstract. I have removed abstract. The model should be abstract.

Comment: Could you flesh out the intended use case here?  Empty types like your `RowPacketData` and `Collection<T>` lead to [weird results](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces) and probably just gets in the way of solving the issue.  And maybe add something about how you intend to use `new Model().get()` and `new DB.get()`... so someone can advise you how to change the class structure to achieve your goals.  Good luck!

Comment: The "problem" is 2 fold. You are asynchronously returning promises, so essentially promises that will return promises. Secondly, there is no class hierarchy between an array of `RowPacketData` and `Collection` so there is no way to cast between them

Comment: @jcalz I am not sure if this answers your question, but what is supposed to happen is when `new DB().where('a', 'b').get()` is called it should return an array of `RowPacketData`, and when `new MyModel().where('a', 'b').get()` is call it should return an object of `Collection<MyModel>` where `myModel extends Model`. Also, Collection is an array wrapper, so it has `length`

Comment: So `Collection<T> extends Array<T>`?  If so, that's very relevant here.   Please try to edit the code into a [mcve].  Do you expect to be able to assign a `Collection<T>` value to a variable of type `RowPacketData[]`?  If not, you will have a problem.  If so, the compiler doesn't seem to understand this.  Either way I'd need a [mcve] in the question itself to give further advice.

Comment: `Collection` does not extend array.

Comment: @jcalz I have updated the question with more information, I hope it is enough but not too much...

Comment: I can't spend time on this now, but my suggestion here is not to use `get()` for two different purposes.  Let the `DB` class have  `protected async getRaw(): Promise<RowDataPacket[]>` and `Model` have `async get(): Promise<Collection<this>>`.  Protecting `getRaw()` should prevent external `DB` users from calling it, and having `Model` return a promise `Collection<this>` might help when you subclass `Model`.

Comment: I noticed that it doesn't care if I return `Promise<T>`, but returning `Promise<Collection<T>>` it doesn't like.

Comment: So does the `getRaw()` suggestion work for you?  If so, I can write it up as an answer along with why it's not valid to have subclasses extend `get()` the way you were doing so.  If not, then ‍♂️